# (Java) Jsoup randomly gets an HTML 503 error when loading pages

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to load a large amount of webpages. Sometimes it works perfectly, but sometimes it throws a 503 error. It's not the same page every time that does it, and I know the website I'm loading is functioning normally. I tried to attach the .ignoreHttpErrors(true) method to my code for connecting, but that just loads the website's error page, as ignoring the error doesn't make it go away. In an instance where a certain page throws a 503, any attempts to load that page in the same run of the program will continue to return a 503, even if the very next time I restart the code there is no error. What can I do about this?

Comment: Find out why the server is giving you a 503 error. The program isn't giving you that error. The _server_ is. You can't just say ignore the errors, because the _server_ isn't going to give you any information. It's like searching for the word 'coffee' on a sheet of paper that doesn't have the word on it. Saying 'ignore errors' doesn't suddenly make the paper have the word. You have to get a paper that has the word.

Comment: Try to add `user agent` and `timeout` to your connection